# Which of the following will set the font of UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

- `UIFont font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f];
  NSDictionary attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font forKey: UITextAttributeFont];
  [segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes: attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];`
- `[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:13.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
- `segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.6f, .6f);`
- None of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIFont font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12.0f];
NSDictionary attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font forKey: UITextAttributeFont];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes: attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

The above code will change font for one particular segmentcontrol whereas the below code will change the font for all segmentcontrol in your app.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:13.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and this code `segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.6f, .6f);` will just scale down your segmentcontrol

**Note:**

Just replace deprecated  `UITextAttributeFont` with `NSFontAttributeName` to work without warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
 [segment setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor darkGrayColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

here `segment` is `UISegmentedControl` object.